# transaction is not happening

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

[image]

Error:

> ```
> 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266   To:                 
> 0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512
>
>   Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with
> reason string 'You Don't have enough funds to donate'
>       at FundMe.fund (contracts/FundMe.sol:61)
>       at FundMe.<fallback> (contracts/FundMe.sol:57)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>       at HardhatNode.runCall (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:652:20)
>       at EthModule._callAction (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:354:9)
>       at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:139:22)
>       at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:116:18)
>       at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:188:20)
>       at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (/home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-fund-me/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:167:17)
>
> eth_blockNumber eth_getBlockByNumber eth_feeHistory
> ```

index.js

````
       import { ethers } from "./ethers-5.6.esm.min.js"
    import { abi, contractAddress } from "./constants.js"
    
    let connectButton = document.getElementById("connect-Btn")
    let fundButton = document.getElementById("fund-Btn")
    
    connectButton.onclick = connect
    fundButton.onclick = fund
    
    async function connect() {
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        try {
          await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
        connectButton.innerText = "Connected!"
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" })
        console.log(accounts)
      } else {
        connectButton.innerText = "Please Install Metamask"
      }
    }
    
    //*fund
    
    async function fund() {
      const ethAmount = "0.1"
      console.log(`Funding with ${ethAmount}....`)
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        //? What we need to send a transaction
        //* provider/connection to blockchain
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        //*signer/wallet/someone with some gas
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        //* contract that we are interacting with
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)
        //* ABI & Address
        const transactionResponse = await contract.fund({
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount),
        })
      }
    }
```
````

github link to smartcontract which im importing in frontend : https://github.com/deepak2301/hardhat-FundMe

Comment: someone else has it. check their Q&A https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/4752#discussioncomment-4885422